# Text Changed event doesn't fire in Gridview after a DataBind()

Tags: .net, events

We have a gidview on a page with a selection of text boxes, each text box has a TextChanged event that updates it's corresponding value in a database.

The page contains a button that when pressed causes a postback and the text changed events fire and all is ok.

When a selected index on a dropdown is changed the grid is rebound but the text changed events do not fire.

The grid is also rebound in the button click event as well but it seems the text changed events fire before the button click but the selected index event fires before the text changed events, I think rebinding the grid has cause the text changed events to be ignored or removed from the control.

Can anyone shed light on this matter. The grid needs to be auto saving itself as the user navigates around.

Thanks

Comment: can you add a sample of what you've done?

Comment: Wait...wait, "_when a selected index on a dropdown is changed_". Where is this `DropDownList`? Why do you rebind the GridView `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and from the `OnClick` of the  button(from within the handlers or from page_load?)? Often code explains much better what you're doing.

Comment: There is no code i've made up a simpler explanation of what i'm doing. It's a grid and it shows data for a year, data can be edited in the gridview directly and saved on a button press, if the user selects a different year then the grid is refreshed, before the refresh I want to save the current years data. This is achieved using text changed events on the text boxes to check they have actually changed but those events do not fire when selected index changed ona drop down but they do fire before a buttons on click event. So only on click saving is working at the moment.

Comment: At the time of SelectedIndexChanged, Text Changed will not fire. You need to force it to fire the event. Other wise when that event fires that time only set whatever you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Re-binding the grid loses all it's events for controls that are embedded in the grid. So when you have drawn a textbox within the grid, you must have added the event handler at that point. You have to re-create event handlers on the databind for it to work.

Comment: I tend to agree, the events for the text boxes are being added in the rowcreated event of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are being subjected to timings in the page lifecycle, where one thing is happening before the other, when you expected \ desired them to occur in a different order.  My workaround is to flip a boolean flag in the SelectedIndexChanged event, and then handle the event in OnLoadCompleted, after the page is completely loaded, and ALL events have fired.  I would like to think there is a better answer, but this solved it for me.

```
#region Fields
private bool switchFirstDataRow_ = false;
#endregion Fields

#region Events
protected void ddlFirstRowOfData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // NOTE: Moved the handling of these changes to OnLoadComplete because the grid view load\events were not firing
    // ......until after these events had alreadyc completed, resulting in grid view changes not saving
    switchFirstDataRow_ = true;
}

protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoadComplete(e);

    // NOTE: Moved the handling of these changes here because the grid view load\events were not firing
    // ......until after these events had already completed, resulting in grid view changes not saving

    // Apply pending first data row changes
    if (switchFirstDataRow_)
    {
        // Do something here to respond to event...
        Controller.SetFirstRowOfData(ddlFirstRowOfData.SelectedIndex + 1);

        // Re-bind the grid
        gvImportConfiguration.DataBind();
    }
}
#endregion Events
```